# ERROR:value for column in the table is DBNull for C# Business Tier

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am using Visual studio 2010 and SQL SERVER management studio 2008 R2

I have a table Order which references table Booking

```
CREATE TABLE [Order]
(OrderNumber int IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
CustNumber int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Customer(CustNumber),
EmpNumber int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Employee(EmpNumber),
OrderDate date,
Deliver char,
StatusID int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES [Status] (StatusID),
BookingNumber int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Booking(BookingNumber),
TotalAmount float,
OutstandingAmount float);
GO

CREATE TABLE Booking
(BookingNumber int IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
BookingDate datetime,
BookingTime datetime,
StatusID int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES [Status](StatusID),
CustNumber int FOREIGN KEY  REFERENCES Customer(CustNumber),
EmpNumber int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Employee(EmpNumber)
);
GO
```

I also have a class Order and ClassList OrderList inheriting from the orderClass

```
 public class Order
{
    public int OrderNumber { set; get;}
    public int CustNumber { set; get;}
    public int EmpNumber { set; get;}
    public DateTime OrderDate { set; get;}
    public char Deliver { set; get;}
    public int StatusID { set; get;}
    public int BookingNumber { set; get; }
    public float TotalAmount { set; get;}
    public float OutstandingAmount { set; get; }


  public Order()
    {
        OrderNumber = 0;
        CustNumber = 0;
        EmpNumber = 0;
        OrderDate = DateTime.Today;
        Deliver = ' ';
        StatusID = 0;
        BookingNumber = 0;
        TotalAmount = 0;
        OutstandingAmount = 0;

    }

    public Order(int a, int b, int c, DateTime d, char e,int f, int g, float h, float i)
    {
        OrderNumber = a;
        CustNumber = b;
        EmpNumber = c;
        OrderDate = d;
        Deliver = e;
        StatusID = f;
        BookingNumber = g;
        TotalAmount = h;
        OutstandingAmount = i;

    }
namespace EAMS_BusinessTier
{
public class OrderList : System.ComponentModel.BindingList <Order>
{private EAMS_DBDataSetTableAdapters.OrderTableAdapter OrderTA = new EAMS_DBDataSetTableAdapters.OrderTableAdapter();
    private EAMS_DBDataSet ds = new EAMS_DBDataSet();


    /////////// Read OrderList //////////////////////////
    public OrderList()
    {
        OrderTA.FillbyOrder(ds.Order);
        foreach (EAMS_DBDataSet.OrderRow r in ds.Order.Rows)
        {
            Order m = new Order(r.OrderNumber,r.CustNumber,r.EmpNumber,r.OrderDate,Convert.ToChar(r.Deliver),r.StatusID,r.BookingNumber,Convert.ToInt32(r.TotalAmount),Convert.ToInt32(r.OutstandingAmount));
            this.Add(m);
        }
    }

    public OrderList(int id)
    {
        OrderTA.FillbyOrder(ds.Order);
        foreach (EAMS_DBDataSet.OrderRow r in ds.Order.Rows)
        {
            if (id == r.OrderNumber)
            {
                Order m = new Order(r.OrderNumber, r.CustNumber, r.EmpNumber, r.OrderDate, Convert.ToChar(r.Deliver), r.StatusID, r.BookingNumber, Convert.ToInt32(r.TotalAmount), Convert.ToInt32(r.OutstandingAmount));
                this.Add(m);
            }
        }
    }
    /////END////


    ///////////////////// get OrderList ////////////////////////
    public OrderList getOrderList()
    {

        return this;
    }

    public OrderList getOrderList(int id)
    {
        OrderList t = new OrderList(id);
        return t;
    }
    ////END////


    /////////////////////  Save Order ////////////////////////
    public void SaveOrder()
    {
        EAMS_DBDataSet.BankDataTable temp = new EAMS_DBDataSet.BankDataTable();

        foreach (Order r in this)
        {
            EAMS_DBDataSet.OrderRow nr = ds.Order.NewOrderRow();
            nr.OrderNumber = r.OrderNumber;
            nr.CustNumber = r.CustNumber;
            nr.EmpNumber = r.EmpNumber;
            nr.OrderDate = r.OrderDate;
            nr.Deliver = Convert.ToString(r.Deliver);
            nr.StatusID = r.StatusID;
            nr.BookingNumber = r.BookingNumber;
            nr.TotalAmount = r.TotalAmount;
            nr.OutstandingAmount = r.OutstandingAmount;


            temp.Rows.Add(nr.ItemArray);
        }

        ds.Order.Merge(temp, false);

        foreach (EAMS_DBDataSet.OrderRow r in ds.Order.Rows)

            if (r.RowState == DataRowState.Unchanged)
            {
                r.Delete();
            }

        OrderTA.Update(ds.Order);
    }
    ////END////


    //////////////// Insert Order //////////////////////////////
    public void InsertOrder(int a, int b, int c, DateTime d, char e, int f,int g,float h,float i)
    {
        Order m = new Order(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i);
        this.Add(m);
    }
    ////END////



    /////////////////Delete Order /////////////////////////
    public void DeleteOrder(int del)
    {
        int i = 0;
        int d = -1;

        foreach (Order r in this)
        {
            if (r.OrderNumber == del)
            {
                d = i;
            }
            i++;
        }
        if (d > -1)
        {
            this.RemoveAt(d);
        }
    }
    ////END////


    /////////////// Update Order ///////////////////////
    public void UpdateOrder(int a, int b, int c, DateTime d, char e, int f, int g, float h, float i)
    {
        Order r = new Order(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i);
        foreach (Order nr in this)
        {
            if (r.OrderNumber == nr.OrderNumber)
            {
                nr.OrderNumber = r.OrderNumber;
                nr.CustNumber = r.CustNumber;
                nr.OrderDate = r.OrderDate;
                nr.Deliver = r.Deliver;
                nr.StatusID = r.StatusID;
                nr.BookingNumber = r.BookingNumber;
                nr.TotalAmount = r.TotalAmount;
                nr.OutstandingAmount = r.OutstandingAmount;


                break;
            }
        }
    }
    ////END////
```

The way this has to work is not every order has a booking number, so it is possible to have a null value for booking number in the Order table.

When I try to load the OrderList in the presentation tier after building the business tier and connecting to the OrderList Data object the error occurs. here is the  code that i used to load the OrderList from the presentation tier

```
using EAMS_BusinessTier;

namespace DXApplication2
{
public partial class Form5 : Form
{
    public Form5()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    internal OrderList OrderLis = new OrderList();
    private void Form5_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        orderListBindingSource.DataSource = OrderLis;
    }
```

I Keep getting this error when I try to load the OrderList at runtime 
"The value for column 'BookingNumber' in table 'Order' is DBNull." how do i handle this error?

Thank you in advance

Comment: The syntax is clearly SQL Server so I removed the MySQL tag.

Answer (score 0):

Change type of Order.BookingNumber from int to `Nullable<int>` . Or just `int?`.

Verify your EDM. The field BookingNumber in table Order must allow nulls.

Change

```
Order m = new Order(r.OrderNumber,r.CustNumber,r.EmpNumber,r.OrderDate,Convert.ToChar(r.Deliver),r.StatusID,r.BookingNumber,Convert.ToInt32(r.TotalAmount),Convert.ToInt32(r.OutstandingAmount));
```

to:

```
Order m = new Order(r.OrderNumber,r.CustNumber,r.EmpNumber,r.OrderDate,Convert.ToChar(r.Deliver),r.StatusID,(int?)r.BookingNumber,Convert.ToInt32(r.TotalAmount),Convert.ToInt32(r.OutstandingAmount));
```

Comment: Ive tried changing the data type of the BookingNumber to 'int?' in the Booking Class and BookingList Class and in the order class and OrderList Class but I am still getting the same error when I try to run the program.

Comment: Now Im getting this error throw new global::System.Data.StrongTypingException("The value for column \'BookingNumber\' in table \'Order\' is DBNull.", e); Could there possibly be a problem anywhere else? like maybe in the database as well?

Comment: basically that field is null in db, so you see this error. As you mentioned in question - it is ok. This error is in mapping db record to .net object.

Comment: So this basically means if I convert my value to int? and still get errors then I am doing something majorly wrong? I will try it out again from scratch and see what happens

Comment: Yep. Basic rule - if your db field can be null, corresponding object property should be nullable.